# Parameter passing in R when interior function arguments are dependent on optional parameters

Tags: r, function, parameters, parameter-passing, optional-parameters

I'm working in R and need to pass arguments to a function so that they can be used as arguments when calling another function within the original. In the example below you can see that I'm interested in calling interiorFunc() every time primaryFunc() is called but the value of the first parameter is dependent on the existence of a second parameter. If I declare 'parameter 2' then I want a different set of arguments than if I don't declare 'parameter 2' in the function call. Here is the definition for the interior function:

```
interiorFunc(data, resp, param1, param2)
{
  if(missing(param2)) 
  { 
    print(paste("Do analysis without parameter 2 on dataset of size",nrow(data),"with response",resp)
  }else{
    print(paste("Do analysis with parameter 2 on dataset of size",nrow(data),"with response",resp))
  }

}
```

And here is the function that calls it:

```
primaryFunc <- function(dataset, ...)
{
  if(parameter 2 has been declared in the call to primaryFunc)
  {
    results <- interiorFunc(dataset, ...)
  }else{
    modifedData <- sample(dataset, 2*dataset, replace = TRUE)
    results <- interiorFunc(modifiedData, ...)
  }

  return(results)
}
```

The function call would either be:

```
interiorFuncResults <- primaryFunc(dataset, response, parameter1)
```

or

```
interiorFuncResults <- primaryFunc(dataset, response, parameter1, parameter2)
```

so I need to determine prior to calling the interior function if it's 'parameter2' value has been passed in. Here is a definition of interiorFunc() to make this example reproducible:

Thank you for your help.

Comment: with the problem as it stands, you can simply test how many extra arguments were passed, as in `length(list(...))`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess I should have made my reproducible example more realistic. interiorFunc() actually takes many parameters (about 10) and about 6 are optional, but only one has the effect that parameter2 in this example does, all the others can be specified without it effecting the primaryFunc().

Comment: i thought that would be :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one of the common strategies is to filter the names,

```
sub <- function(x, y, param=NULL, ...){
  if(!is.null(param))
    message(param, "is being used") else
      message("not seeing it")
}

main <- function(a=1, b=2, ..., c=3){

  dots <- list(...)

  if("param" %in% names(dots))
    sub(a, b, ...) else
      sub(a, b, ...)

}

main(z=2)

main(param = 2)
```

which, of course, assumes that `...` only will receive fully named arguments.

Comment: The more common approach is to make `param = NULL` an argument to `main`, use `if(is.null(param))`, and pass it down explicitly.

Comment: probably; let's call it the more common approach to dealing with extraction of specific parameters from `...`